# html canvas drawimage method - image and text not displaying

Tags: html, canvas, drawimage

This is for an assignment, I'm supposed to make the user type two small strings of text that will be applied over an image inside a canvas. They are not being displayed, though. I tried the "onload" method suggested on a similar question but it didnt work. Any help?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
 <body>

  <img id="imgBgMeme" src="meme.jpg" alt="image meme" style="display:none;"/>
 
     <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" id="memecanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas><br>
  
  
  <div>
  O primeiro texto digitado foi:<span id="texto1"></span><br/>
  O segundo texto digitado foi:<span id="texto2"></span><br/>
  </div>

 
  <script type="text/javascript">
   
   
  //typed text test
  var txt_1 = prompt("Sentence 1:");
  var txt_2 = prompt("Sentence 2:");
  
  //typed text
  document.getElementById("texto1").innerHTML = txt_1;
  document.getElementById("texto2").innerHTML = txt_2;
    
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     
  var image = document.getElementById("imgBgMeme");
  image.onload = function() {
     
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, cv.width, cv.height); 
 }
  
  //custom txt
  ctx.font = "36pt Impact";
  ctx.textAlign = center;
 
   
  // draw txts over image
  ctx.fillText(txt_1, cv.width / 2, 60); 
  ctx.strokeText(txt_1, cv.width / 2, 60);
   
  ctx.fillText(txt_2, cv.width / 2, 460); 
  ctx.strokeText(txt_2, cv.width / 2, 460);

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ctx` is not defined

Comment: thanks, i substituted "context" for "ctx" but that didn't help. still not loading.

Comment: Check your console, you have a lot of Reference Errors to fix. Once done, you'll face the issue that by the time your code after the prompt executes, your image will already have have loaded, and hence its `onload` event too, so you may want to check its `.naturalWidth` property to know if you have to manually call it (`if(image.naturalWidth) image.onload();`)